# Python "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQL_Wrapper'" when the SQL_Wrapper module exists in the correct location

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

Hi I am trying to run a python script in Visual Studio Code where I need to import the SQL_Wrapper module.  All of my other modules are importing fine, but I keep getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQL_Wrapper'".

When I try to install the SQL_Wrapper I am told that the requirement is already satisfied.  I've checked that the paths match and have tried using a virtual environment.  Nothing has worked.

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\virtual environment> & "c:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/virtual environment/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/NAMER-queries/OI/import.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\NAMER-queries\OI\import.py", line 13, in <module>
    from SQL_Wrapper.SQLWrapper import SQLWrapper as SQL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQL_Wrapper'
(.venv) PS C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\virtual environment> py -m pip install SQL_Wrapper
Requirement already satisfied: SQL_Wrapper in c:\users\User\onedrive\documents\virtual environment\.venv\lib\site-packages (0.1)
```

Would appreciate help if anyone knows how to fix this issue.

Comment: A module of a certain name does not necessarily correspond 1:1 with a package bearing the same name on PyPi; if you're not fully understanding of the `SQL_Wrapper` PyPi package contains, you should uninstall it.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not an image.

Comment: where is the code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code ?

Comment: it's encountering this code `from SQL_Wrapper.SQLWrapper import SQLWrapper as SQL` but can't find the module `'SQL_Wrapper'` to import from

Comment: is it just me but i can't find `SQL_Wrapper` package online. However, I can see `sqlwrapper0.1` and `sql-wrapper 0.1`

Comment: so how did you get this `py -m pip install SQL_Wrapper` ?